# Set a returned pointer NULL doesn't work?

Tags: c++

I'm currently facing a Problem where I **can't set a returned pointer NULL**.

Here's a *simplified version* of my *code*:

```
const Item* Stack::removeItem() {
    return pointer_to_item;
}
```

Now I'm **trying** to delete this Item and **set it to NULL**

```
bool Slots::removeItem(const Item & item) {

    Item const *temp = stack[index]->removeItem(item);
    delete temp;
    temp = NULL;

    return true;
}
```

This **doesn't set** the returned **pointer to NULL**. The next time the item is accessed from the stack, variables are not set (like a memeber variable "id" in Item).

If I set it to NULL **like this**, **it works just fine**:

```
const Item* Stack::removeItem() {
    pointer_to_item = NULL;
    return pointer_to_item;
}
```

Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: `temp` is a local variable. Anything you do to it remains in the scope of the `removeItem` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you basically want is something like this:

```
const Item* Stack::removeItem() {
    Item *temp = pointer_to_item;
    pointer_to_item = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
Item const *temp = stack[index]->removeItem(item);
delete temp;
temp = NULL;
```

You only reset your local variable `temp`, the content of the `stack` doesn't change.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out! is it possible to delete the returned element and set it to NULL?

Comment: What is the type of your `stack`?

Comment: `Slots` holds a `Stack**` Array and `Stack` holds an `Item**` Array, so the type of stack is `Stack**`

Comment: But what is `Stack`? It's certainly not `std::stack`. What library does it belong to? Do you have documentation of that library? Have you written it yourself?

Comment: I wrote it myself, it's real type is `ItemStack`. I simplified my code snippets for SO. Basically `removeItem()` in `Slots` calls `removeItem()` for every `Stack` in the stack Array. If the item is found, it is returned to `removeItem()` in `Slots` where it should be deleted and set to NULL.